# How to open file from app in ChromeOS Files App?

Tags: javascript, default, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

Merry Christmas! While working on my own Chrome App's main window, I noticed that I could set it to be the default app to open files.

Perhaps I overlooked the [API Index](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), but I can't seem to find an API or snippet that allows this. I need to know the JavaScript that will send a command to my app telling it to open a file. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance. Attached I have a screenshot that shows my default code editor (Caret) being shown to open "main.js".

[image: Example of default app]

Comment: See here - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/file_handlers

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be it!

Comment: @levi Avoid answering in comments!

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I was thinking. I can't accept an answer if it's posted as a comment. ;)